# How to enable build speed window in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

I just came to know that in the latest Android Studio 4.0, there is a Build Speed Window which will help to understand and diagnose issues with the build process. But somehow, that Build Speed Window is not appearing after the build is successful. Does anyone know how to enable the build speed window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Android Studio 4.0 Canary 3**

**Android Gradle plugin 4.0.0-alpha03 and higher**

Step 1:  Build > Make Project from the menu bar

Step 2: Select View > Tool Windows > Build from the menu bar.

After Android Studio finishes building your project, Open the Build Speed window in one of the following ways:

Step 3:  Click the Build Speed tab. or Click the link in the right side of the Build Output window.

If you are using android studio 4.0 beta channel, build speed is known as build analyzer.

[image]
refer this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#build-attribution).

I hope this helps.

Comment: using AS 4.0.0 Beta 4. I run build or select Build -> Make Project and after build is done there is no Build Analyzer or Build Speed... nothing :(

Comment: @bio007 did you try step 3?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDiZI.png You mean the step to click on non-existent tab? [AS 4.0.0 beta 4, 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-beta04', gradle-6.1.1-all.zip]

Comment: @bio007 The Build Analyzer is **disabled** in Android Studio 4.0 [Beta 4](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#4-0-ki-build-analyzer). It will be re-enabled in Beta 5.

Comment: thank you, didn't noticed it in the release page before

Comment: I am using AS 4.0 RC 1, ans i have the same problem..now tab for Build speed exists after build completes.

Answer (score 1):

@josepraveen answers is the correct one. I just want to add that you should also make sure that you have `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0` under dependencies in the build.gradle of the parent
Then do the step 1 etc

[image]